# retrieve html and XML from a string with php

Tags: php, html, xml

My project is to use CKEditor and create a plugin to create chart inside the page which will display the result
(in CKEditor just an img will appear when you use the plugin).

The plugin is already created,
when you use it, XML with the value and attribute needed is created inside CKEditor.
So the XML for the chart exist with writing text (format as `<p>` by CKEditor).

When you save inside the CKEditor, the XML and the text as HTML are sent to the database inside a string
(when I retrieve data from CKEditor it send a string).

Inside the database it is stored like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <onglet pos="1" name="test">
        <wysiwyg>
            <code>
                &lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
                &#xD;
                &lt;p&gt;&lt;graphique drawer="Line" interval="2" periode="semaine" titre="test" type="Relative"&gt;
                    &lt;serie marqueur="Normal"&gt;
                        &lt;index serial="---" type="di"&gt;3&lt;/index&gt;
                        &lt;typegroupe&gt;&lt;/typegroupe&gt;
                        &lt;intervalgroup&gt;&lt;/intervalgroup&gt;
                        &lt;periodgroup&gt;&lt;/periodgroup&gt;
                        &lt;groupverif&gt;non&lt;/groupverif&gt;
                        &lt;unite&gt;Kwh&lt;/unite&gt;
                        &lt;legend&gt;test2&lt;/legend&gt;
                        &lt;color&gt;#000000&lt;/color&gt;
                    &lt;/serie&gt;
                 &lt;/graphique&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;
            </code>
        </wysiwyg>
    </onglet>
</configuration>
```

I get it inside a php page to displays my text and chart from CKEditor

Like this:

```
$test=200;  //ID
$testxml=loadxml($test);
$testonglet=$testxml->onglet;
$testwysiwyg=$testonglet->wysiwyg;
$testcode=$testwysiwyg->code;
```

loadxml is a php function in another file:

```
$loadXml = THE QUERY TO RETRIEVE THE XML FROM THE DB
$reqload = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($loadXml));
$decode = html_entity_decode($reqload[0]);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($decode);
       return $xml;
```

Now if I do var_dump($testcode);

I got:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) { [0]=> string(403) "

test

4nonKwhtest2#000000

test après graph
" }
```

test and test après graph are just text but the 4nonKwhtest2#000000 are the XML value from the plugin chart.

**I would like to parse the string to retrive the text and the XML (with his structure since I need it to create the chart with php).**

I have already tested:

```
$testXML = Simplexml_load_string($testcode);
var_dump($testXML);
```

It gave me:

```
bool(false)
```

I have the same from XMLReader.

I also tested:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($testcode);
```

It gave something with the text but I couldn't retrieve my XML from it.

I don't know how to handle this anymore, it's the first time I use PHP

I hope it's more clear like this (sorry for my english).

Comment: If you have HTML/XML as a string value inside a text node, you will have to parse the string into a second document: Please edit your question and provide better information.

Comment: Next to what @ThW said, Stackoverflow is about programming questions. That's best with some little code and working example that demonstrates your issue. Would make things more clear, too. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edit my post 2 days ago (unfortunatly I didn't know you where warned of the change).  @ThW when you say parse into a second document you mean with DOMDocument ?

Comment: You need to post an example of the XML you get from the database, "HERE WHAT I GET FROM CKEDITOR" is not enough. However here is an example how to get HTML stored as text inside XML: https://eval.in/303230

Comment: I edit the questions.  @ThW it's not really retrieve HTML inside XML, but inside my XML I have a string (code) that contain HTML and XML.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have an XML document that contains another XML fragment as a text node.

That means you need to load the outer XML document first, read the text node and append the XML fragment to a new XML document.

## Load The Outer XML / Read The Fragment:

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows to fetch nodes and values from a XML DOM using XPath expression.

```
$outer = new DOMDocument();
$outer->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($outer);
$innerXml = $xpath->evaluate('string(/configuration/onglet/wysiwyg/code)');
echo $innerXml;
```

Output:

```
<p>test</p>            
<p><graphique drawer="Line" interval="2" periode="semaine" titre="test" type="Relative">
  <serie marqueur="Normal">
    <index serial="---" type="di">3</index>
    <typegroupe></typegroupe>
    <intervalgroup></intervalgroup>
    <periodgroup></periodgroup>
    <groupverif>non</groupverif>
    <unite>Kwh</unite>
    <legend>test2</legend>
    <color>#000000</color>
  </serie>
</graphique></p>
```

## Load The XML Fragment

XML documents have a single root/document element node, so the XML in the case is a fragment. For easy reading it needs the single root node. So lets create a document with a `body` node and append the fragment to it:

```
$inner = new DOMDocument();
$inner->appendChild($inner->createElement('body'));
$fragment = $inner->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXml($innerXml);
$inner->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);
echo $inner->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
  <p>test</p>            
  <p><graphique drawer="Line" interval="2" periode="semaine" titre="test" type="Relative">
    <serie marqueur="Normal">
      <index serial="---" type="di">3</index>
      <typegroupe></typegroupe>
      <intervalgroup></intervalgroup>
      <periodgroup></periodgroup>
      <groupverif>non</groupverif>
      <unite>Kwh</unite>
      <legend>test2</legend>
      <color>#000000</color>
    </serie>
  </graphique></p>
</body>
```

The element name doesn't matter, but `body` fits the `p` elements.

## Read Data From The New Document

Now it is possible to create an `DOMXPath` instance for the document and fetch data from it.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($inner);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//graphique') as $graphique) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'drawer' => $graphique->getAttribute('drawer'),
      'serie-color' => $xpath->evaluate('string(serie/color)', $graphique)
    ]
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["drawer"]=>
  string(4) "Line"
  ["serie-color"]=>
  string(7) "#000000"
}
```